# How do I assign image and label values from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, swift

I am passing data(image and Label) from one view controller to another. I am storing them in a NSDictionary, and the data is being passed to the new viewcontroller. I have connected a image view as well as a label. How do I assign the image and the label the values in the NSDictionary? Below is the code for transferring the data from one view controller to another.

```
var dicSelected : NSDictionary!
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
print("Cell \(indexPath.item) selected")
print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item])
 self.dicSelected = ["friendname" : arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item], "friendimage" :  arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item]]
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: dicSelected)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){

    let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfilePages

    nextViewOBJ.dicData = self.dicSelected;

}
}
```

Below is the code for the FriendProfilePages.

```
@IBOutlet weak var friendimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var friendname: UILabel!
var dicData : NSDictionary?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
print("Dictionary: \(self.dicData)")
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can create a model class with properties

```
var image: UIImage?
var text: String?
```

and then pass that class's object to next view controller and assign those values to your `friendimage.image` and `friendname.text`

**Code for FriendProfilePages:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var friendimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var friendname: UILabel!
var dataModel : DataModel?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   friendimage.image = dataModel.image
   friendname.text = dataModel.text
}
```

**Now For performing Segue**

```
var selectedData = DataModel()

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   print("Cell \(indexPath.item) selected")
   print(arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item])

   self.selectedData.text = arrayOfFriendsNames[index] as? String
   self.selectedData.image = arrayOfFriends[index] as? UIImage
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: dicSelected)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if(segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){
    let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfilePages
    nextViewOBJ.dataModel = self.selectedData;
   }
}
```

**Declare it anywhere**

```
class DataModel : NSObject {
   var image: UIImage?
   var text: String?
}
```

just to get you an idea...

Comment: Would I create a model class in the FriendProfilePages?

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper types to transfer data rather than dictionaries. You could define an appropriate type like this

```
struct FriendProfileData {
  let name:  String
  let image: UIImage
}
```

You'll need to update your selection code to create one of these new structs like this

```
var selected: FriendProfileData

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  selected = FriendProfileData(name: arrayOfFriendsNames[indexPath.item], image: arrayOfFriends[indexPath.item])
  performSegueWithIdentifier("friendaccess", sender: self)
}
```

Your `prepareForSegue` needs to then change to

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if (segue.identifier == "friendaccess"){
    guard let selected = selected else {
      return
    }

    let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendProfilePages
    nextViewOBJ.dicData = selected;
  }
}
```

Then in the viewDidAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)

  friendImage.image = selected.image
  friendName.text   = selected.name
}
```